# Not-found="ignore" behaviour in Castle Activerecord

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Is it possible to implement the 'not-found="ignore"' behaviour of NHibernate on a key mapping when using Castle Activerecord?

I am using existing legacy Castle Activerecord classes within an ASP.Net web application to map to a legacy, read only, MSSQL database. I cannot alter the database in any way.

The parent Product table has a relationship with a Type table, however the Product table contains numerous records with Type values containing a 0 which have not been given an equivalent record on the Type table.

I have been asked to add the mapping between the Product and Type class and need to ignore the occurrences of broken referential integrity if possible. The 'not-found="ignore"' method would be the way I would go about this using vanilla NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord relation attributes have a [`NotFoundBehavior` property](http://api.castleproject.org/html/P_Castle_ActiveRecord_RelationAttribute_NotFoundBehaviour.htm) that maps to NHibernate's `not-found`

[Here's an example.](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.Tests/Model/NotFoundBehaviourClass.cs)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have added a GetProductType() method to the Product class to retrieve the Type.

I am still interested for a configurable way to do this with Castle though  :)